# How to use array list in FileOutputStream

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have two byte arrays which I have put in an array list.The Code for which is here:

```
ArrayList al = new ArrayList();    
FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream(bin);
fis.read(file, 0, 2048);
metas="123456789123";
meta=metas.getBytes();
al.add(meta);
al.add(file);
```

But when I try to put it in an output stream like this
    fos.write(al.toArray());

It gives the error As

> no suitable method found for write(Object[])
>       method FileOutputStream.write(byte[],int,int) is not applicable

what may be the problem

Comment: Sidenote: the `fis.read(...)` not necesarily reads all 2k data into `file` (I guess file is an array). It reads what it has available. You must call read repeteadely until 2k is readed, or until read returns `<=0` (end of file). It's not generating the problem you have, but will be an issue later.

Comment: What exactly do you want to write in that file? Both byte arrays?

Comment: Try to use ObjectOutputStream.

Comment: Yes, One array consists of some data that will be added to every 2k of data(I know that i have to set up a loop) and the other will contain that data,both have to be written as one single unit.

Comment: Instead of adding the data to a list, you can write the bytes directly to a file.

Comment: @ixos ObjectOutputStream worked

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you want to do. If you want to write both the byte arrays in a file use:

```
for(byte[] arr: al) {
    fos.write(arr);
}
```